# Jquery Chosen hide target on source change?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen jquery plugin and i have two select fields one is `source` and other is `target`

```
<select data-placeholder="Source language" class="chzn-select" id="os_source" style="width:200px;">
                    <option value=""></option> 
                    <option value="246">Somali</option>
                    <option value="239">Swahili</option>
                    <option value="259">Zulu</option>
                    <option value="237">Tigrinya</option>
                    <option value="261">Afrikaans</option>
                    <option value="236">Amharic</option>
                    <option value="265">Polish</option>
                    <option value="241">Czech</option>
                    <option value="3476">English</option>
                    <option value="281">German</option>
                    <option value="285">Romanian</option>
                    <option value="243">Arabic</option>
                    <option value="299">Chinese</option>
                    <option value="401">French</option>
                    <option value="402">Italian</option>
                    <option value="403">Russian</option>
                    <option value="404">Spanish</option>
                    <option value="405">Turkish</option>

              </select>



<select data-placeholder="Target language" class="chzn-select" id="os_target" multiple style="width:200px">
                    <option value=""></option> 
                    <option value="246">Somali</option>
                    <option value="239">Swahili</option>
                    <option value="259">Zulu</option>
                    <option value="237">Tigrinya</option>
                    <option value="261">Afrikaans</option>
                    <option value="236">Amharic</option>
                    <option value="265">Polish</option>
                    <option value="241">Czech</option>
                    <option value="3476">English</option>
                    <option value="281">German</option>
                    <option value="285">Romanian</option>
                    <option value="243">Arabic</option>
                    <option value="299">Chinese</option>
                    <option value="401">French</option>
                    <option value="402">Italian</option>
                    <option value="403">Russian</option>
                    <option value="404">Spanish</option>
                    <option value="405">Turkish</option>

              </select>
```

I want to make the target language hide on choosing the same source language ( when user chose english in source , english disappear in target and so on )

How can achieve that ?

```
 $('#os_source').chosen().change(function() {
    var source = $(this).val();

        $('.chzn-results').val(source).hide();
         $("#os_target").trigger("liszt:updated");

});
```

Here is the demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/LUYcA/60/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#os_source').chosen().change(function(){
    $("#os_target option").attr("disabled",false);
    var source = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    $("#os_target option[value="+source+"]").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#os_target").trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

The reason I haven't used `.hide()` is it has some cross browser issues when used on the `option` tag.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LUYcA/61/

Comment: Thanks for telling me, I've just updated it and now it's working as expected.

Comment: Hi @Joe this doesn't apply for the Chosen Jquery plugin, http://jsfiddle.net/LUYcA/60/

Comment: Just updated again and I've tested it with the chosen plugin - it's working great!